# Object Creation depending on Generic Type

Tags: java, generics

I have the following generic interface:

```
public interface I<T> {
  void method(T key);
}
```

which it is implemented by two different classes (A y B).

```
public class A implements I<Integer> {
  @Override
  void method(Integer key) {
    //do smth
  }

public class B implements I<String> {
  @Override
  void method(String key) {
    //do smth 
  }
```

Futhermore, there is a Java class MyClass where a new instance of A or B is created depending on the T param.

```
public class MyClass<T> {
  public void f() {
    I<T> object = //here is the problem
  }
}
```

My question is the following:

Is it possible to achieve it without passing the object of T class?

Comment: The real question, of course, is why would you like to structure your code this way. Pass an `I<T>` as a parameter to the `MyClass<T>`'s method `f()`, or even to its constructor. That moves the problem up to where you may be better suited to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no.  you have to have something concrete to disambiguate the instantiation.  remember, at runtime the generic bindings are gone (they are only syntactic sugar).  if you doubt this, compile the same code with and without the  generic hints.  the output classes will be bytewise identical.

you basically have to have "some concrete reference to a type", either as presented by Igor above, or something else (Class.forName( "ClassName" ), ClassName.class, etc.) or dynamically build a class via java.lang.reflect.Proxy.

Igor's example just creates an anonymous factory as a lambda, but in the end, he's still passing the reference to a class, wrapped in a factory method, and bound as a lambda.

now something you "could" do, if you want to pass the Class, you could change your  binding to  or something similar, and pass a Class reference to use for instantiation.  then you can do something like

```
_pass_in_ref.newInstance();
_pass_in_ref::new
etc.
```

caveat emptory

Answer (score 1):

Pass a Supplier.

```
class MyClass<T> {
    public void f(Supplier<I<T>> supplier) {
        I<T> object = supplier.get();
    }
}

new MyClass<String>().f(B::new);
new MyClass<Integer>().f(A::new);
```